# Makefile Grammar

Tags: makefile, format

Is there anywhere a *precise* makefile grammar definition? Or at least some common subset since I guess that there are some flavors. Such a grammar that could be used for writing a parser.

[GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) doesn't seem to be that precise. It would require some guessing and trial-and-error to write a parser for makefile based on that document.

I also found a [similar question on ANTLR mail list](http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2006-December/018856.html). But it remained unanswered which kind of suggests the answer...

Comment: Great question.  I'm disappointed that there's nothing out there -- would be a great aid in learning.  And as you pointed out, clearly `make` knows its language ... why can't we?? :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems there is no official grammar for gnu make, and ...

> It would be tricky to write a grammar for make, since the grammar is
>   extremely context-dependent.

As said by Paul D. Smith in [a message in the gnu make mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-make@gnu.org/msg02778.html). Paul D. Smith is the official maintainer of gnu make.

Comment: On the other hand thou `make` somehow does parse the makefiles and allows some and rejects others...

Answer (score 19):

I made GNU Make's grammar for myself, you can find the grammar and overview of lexer below. It's not perfect, but it can serve as a starting point for someone who wants something better. Some additional and background information is in the [post](https://reversed.top/2019-02-28/inventing-grammar-for-gnu-make/).

Implementation: [lexer](https://github.com/xaizek/zograscope/blob/612bd84285f318ca0a8be50fb9f56dd0479d4594/src/make/make-lexer.flex) and [parser](https://github.com/xaizek/zograscope/blob/612bd84285f318ca0a8be50fb9f56dd0479d4594/src/make/make-parser.ypp).

**[Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)'s dump of the grammar**

```
/* Assign lower precedence to NL. */
/* %precedence NL */
/* %precedence COMMENT "ifdef" "ifndef" "ifeq" "ifneq" */

  1  makefile: statements "end of file"
  2          | "end of file"

  3  statements: br
  4            | statement
  5            | statements br
  6            | statements statement

  7  conditional: if_eq_kw condition statements_opt "endif" comment_opt br
  8             | if_eq_kw condition statements_opt "else" statements_opt "endif" comment_opt br
  9             | if_eq_kw condition statements_opt "else" conditional
 10             | if_def_kw identifier statements_opt "endif" comment_opt br
 11             | if_def_kw identifier statements_opt "else" statements_opt "endif" comment_opt br
 12             | if_def_kw identifier statements_opt "else" conditional

 13  conditional_in_recipe: if_eq_kw condition recipes_opt "endif" comment_opt
 14                       | if_eq_kw condition recipes_opt "else" recipes_opt "endif" comment_opt
 15                       | if_eq_kw condition recipes_opt "else" conditional_in_recipe
 16                       | if_def_kw identifier recipes_opt "endif" comment_opt
 17                       | if_def_kw identifier recipes_opt "else" recipes_opt "endif" comment_opt
 18                       | if_def_kw identifier recipes_opt "else" conditional_in_recipe

 19  condition: '(' expressions_opt ',' expressions_opt ')'
 20           | SLIT SLIT

 21  define: "define" pattern definition "endef" br
 22        | specifiers "define" pattern definition "endef" br
 23        | "define" pattern ASSIGN_OP definition "endef" br
 24        | specifiers "define" pattern ASSIGN_OP definition "endef" br

 25  definition: comment_opt br
 26            | comment_opt br exprs_in_def br

 27  include: "include" expressions br

 28  statements_opt: comment_opt br
 29                | comment_opt br statements

 30  if_def_kw: "ifdef"
 31           | "ifndef"

 32  if_eq_kw: "ifeq"
 33          | "ifneq"

 34  statement: COMMENT
 35           | assignment br
 36           | function br
 37           | rule
 38           | conditional
 39           | define
 40           | include
 41           | export br

 42  export: "export"
 43        | "unexport"
 44        | assignment_prefix
 45        | assignment_prefix WS targets

 46  assignment: pattern ASSIGN_OP comment_opt
 47            | pattern ASSIGN_OP exprs_in_assign comment_opt
 48            | assignment_prefix ASSIGN_OP comment_opt
 49            | assignment_prefix ASSIGN_OP exprs_in_assign comment_opt

 50  assignment_prefix: specifiers pattern

 51  specifiers: "override"
 52            | "export"
 53            | "unexport"
 54            | "override" "export"
 55            | "export" "override"
 56            | "undefine"
 57            | "override" "undefine"
 58            | "undefine" "override"

 59  expressions_opt: %empty
 60                 | expressions

 61  expressions: expression
 62             | expressions WS expression

 63  exprs_nested: expr_nested
 64              | exprs_nested WS expr_nested

 65  exprs_in_assign: expr_in_assign
 66                 | exprs_in_assign WS expr_in_assign

 67  exprs_in_def: first_expr_in_def
 68              | br
 69              | br first_expr_in_def
 70              | exprs_in_def br
 71              | exprs_in_def WS expr_in_recipe
 72              | exprs_in_def br first_expr_in_def

 73  first_expr_in_def: char_in_def expr_in_recipe
 74                   | function expr_in_recipe
 75                   | char_in_def
 76                   | function

 77  exprs_in_recipe: expr_in_recipe
 78                 | exprs_in_recipe WS expr_in_recipe

 79  expression: expression_text
 80            | expression_function

 81  expr_nested: expr_text_nested
 82             | expr_func_nested

 83  expr_in_assign: expr_text_in_assign
 84                | expr_func_in_assign

 85  expr_in_recipe: expr_text_in_recipe
 86                | expr_func_in_recipe

 87  expression_text: text
 88                 | expression_function text

 89  expr_text_nested: text_nested
 90                  | expr_func_nested text_nested

 91  expr_text_in_assign: text_in_assign
 92                     | expr_func_in_assign text_in_assign

 93  expr_text_in_recipe: text_in_recipe
 94                     | expr_func_in_recipe text_in_recipe

 95  expression_function: function
 96                     | '(' exprs_nested ')'
 97                     | expression_text function
 98                     | expression_function function

 99  expr_func_nested: function
100                  | '(' exprs_nested ')'
101                  | expr_func_nested function
102                  | expr_text_nested function

103  expr_func_in_assign: function
104                     | expr_func_in_assign function
105                     | expr_text_in_assign function

106  expr_func_in_recipe: function
107                     | expr_func_in_recipe function
108                     | expr_text_in_recipe function

109  function: VAR
110          | "$(" function_name ")"
111          | "$(" function_name WS arguments ")"
112          | "$(" function_name ',' arguments ")"
113          | "$(" function_name ':' expressions ")"
114          | "$(" function_name ASSIGN_OP expressions ")"

115  function_name: function_name_text
116               | function_name_function

117  function_name_text: function_name_piece
118                    | function_name_function function_name_piece

119  function_name_piece: CHARS
120                     | function_name_piece CHARS

121  function_name_function: function
122                        | function_name_text function

123  arguments: %empty
124           | argument
125           | arguments ','
126           | arguments ',' argument

127  argument: expressions

128  rule: targets colon prerequisites NL
129      | targets colon prerequisites recipes NL
130      | targets colon assignment NL

131  target: pattern

132  pattern: pattern_text
133         | pattern_function

134  pattern_text: identifier
135              | pattern_function identifier

136  pattern_function: function
137                  | pattern_text function
138                  | pattern_function function

139  prerequisites: %empty
140               | targets

141  targets: target
142         | targets WS target

143  recipes: recipe
144         | recipes recipe

145  recipes_opt: comment_opt NL
146             | comment_opt recipes NL

147  recipe: LEADING_TAB exprs_in_recipe
148        | NL conditional_in_recipe
149        | NL COMMENT

150  identifier: CHARS
151            | ','
152            | '('
153            | ')'
154            | identifier CHARS
155            | identifier keywords
156            | identifier ','
157            | identifier '('
158            | identifier ')'

159  text: char
160      | text char

161  text_nested: char_nested
162             | text_nested char_nested

163  text_in_assign: char_in_assign
164                | text_in_assign char_in_assign

165  text_in_recipe: char_in_recipe
166                | text_in_recipe char_in_recipe

167  char: CHARS
168      | SLIT
169      | ASSIGN_OP
170      | ':'

171  char_nested: char
172             | ','

173  char_in_assign: char_nested
174                | '('
175                | ')'
176                | keywords

177  char_in_def: char
178             | '('
179             | ')'
180             | ','
181             | COMMENT
182             | "include"
183             | "override"
184             | "export"
185             | "unexport"
186             | "ifdef"
187             | "ifndef"
188             | "ifeq"
189             | "ifneq"
190             | "else"
191             | "endif"
192             | "define"
193             | "undefine"

194  char_in_recipe: char_in_assign
195                | COMMENT

196  keywords: "include"
197          | "override"
198          | "export"
199          | "unexport"
200          | "ifdef"
201          | "ifndef"
202          | "ifeq"
203          | "ifneq"
204          | "else"
205          | "endif"
206          | "define"
207          | "endef"
208          | "undefine"

209  br: NL
210    | LEADING_TAB

211  colon: ':'
212       | ':' ':'

213  comment_opt: %empty
214             | COMMENT
```

**Some lexer details**

- All in `'` and almost all in `"` quotes are literals.
- `')' ::= <unpaired )>`
- `'}' ::= <unpaired }>`
- `"$(" ::= "$(" | "${"` – beginning of an expansion
- `")" ::= ")" | "}"` – ending of an expansion
- `"end of file" ::= <end of file>`
- `COMMENT ::= <# comment (can be multiline)>`
- `ASSIGN_OP ::= "=" | "?=" | ":=" | "::=" | "+=" | "!="`
- `CHARS ::= <sequence of non-whitespace>`
- `WS ::= <sequence of whitespace>`
- `NL ::= "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n"`
- `VAR ::= /\$./`
- `SLIT ::= <single- or double-quote literal>`
- `LEADING_TAB ::= <tabulation at the first position in a line (eats NL)>`

Whitespace handling is tricky: lexer should ignore it unless previously
returned token needs that whitespace after it.

Unpaired closing parts of expansions (`)` or `}`) are just themselves.
While contents of `$(...)` or `${...}` is never a keyword.

---

**Addressing confusion**

Two comments express the same question:

> On the other hand thou `make` somehow does parse the makefiles and allows some and rejects others...

You don't need a grammar to parse a languages. However, it's a nice thing to have.

In general, there are more possible languages than there are formal grammars, because grammars have constraints which exclude some languages.

I guess that `make` reads input and processes it at the same time while managing state, such that at every point it knows what kind of input it can accept next and what to do with it. Formal languages lean to being context-free, which means that they don't keep much record about their state. It's this gap, which makes it hard to formalize `make`'s language, even though implementing it without a grammar is still possible.