# What is the difference between using a Makefile and CMake to compile the code?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

I code in C/C++ and use a (GNU) Makefile to compile the code. I can do the same with CMake and get a Makefile. However, what is the difference between using a Makefile and CMake to compile the code?

Answer (score 722, accepted):

Make (or rather a Makefile) is a buildsystem - it drives the compiler and other build tools to build your code.

CMake is a generator of buildsystems. It can produce Makefiles, it can produce Ninja build files, it can produce KDEvelop or Xcode projects, it can produce Visual Studio solutions. From the same starting point, the same CMakeLists.txt file. So if you have a platform-independent project, CMake is a way to make it buildsystem-independent as well.

If you have Windows developers used to Visual Studio and Unix developers who swear by GNU Make, CMake is (one of) the way(s) to go.

I would always recommend using CMake (or another buildsystem generator, but CMake is my personal preference) if you intend your project to be multi-platform or widely usable. CMake itself also provides some nice features like dependency detection, library interface management, or integration with CTest, CDash and CPack.

Using a buildsystem generator makes your project more future-proof. Even if you're GNU-Make-only now, what if you later decide to expand to other platforms (be it Windows or something embedded), or just want to use an IDE?

Comment: thank you! Just to confirm, that if I only program on Linux environment than only makefile is adequate but if I want the program from Linux to run in Mac than cmake is better option as I understand that, we don't need to make a new makefile on the Mac but rather just run the cmake. Is that the whole point?

Comment: @rish Yes, that's the gist. Note however, that there's more ways to program on Linux than Makefiles - see e.g. QtCreator, KDEvelop, Ninja. For each of these, it's either "create a project and keep it in sync with the Makefile," or "re-run CMake." And, as the answer mentions, CMake has other functionality too, like dependency discovery (e.g. [`find_package()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html)) or testing/packaging support.

Comment: I read that CMake cannot create non-recursive makefiles. Is that still true?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin What exactly do you mean with "recursive" or "non-recursive" makefiles? Makefiles generated by CMake have a well-defined 3-level hierarchy without loops back up, if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Angew _Non-recursive_ is when make is invoked once with complete project dependency tree. As opposed to _recursive_ when a top level makefile invokes sub-project makefiles in certain order.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin OK; by this definition, it creates recursive makefiles.

Comment: This is an important weakness of CMake - GNU make has its wrinkles, but if you take the time to learn it, it is extremely powerful and versatile, and works on an enormous amount of platforms. Not having a complete dependency tree to analyze is a major flaw, just google for 'recursive make considered harmful'.

Comment: @ErikAlapää I will read the article in detail, but from a first glance - they seem to be talking about recursive make where the depth of recursion is data-driven (i.e. depends on source directory depth etc.). That's not the case with CMake: the total depth of make invocations is always 3, regardless of project structure. It's just that some bits are delegated to a submakefile instead of all in one, but it does *not* reflect project structure in any way. Plus, the submakefiles are not really "self-contained", so they don't suffer the over/under dependency problem.

Comment: @Angew If make is invoked on a sub-makefile instead of including into main makefile, then, by definition, make will only see part of the dependency tree.

Comment: @ErikAlapää The recursivity of generated makefiles, and the rationale for it, is also handled in [CMake's official wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_generate_recursive_Makefiles.3F).

Comment: This post [CMake vs Make](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/01/cmake-vs-make/) explains more. So it's more reasonable to compare CMake with [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System), `configure` and `make`.

Comment: So in 2022 should we still prefer CMake or there might be some new tools?

Comment: @Rainning For me, CMake is still the way to go (but there's certainly a familiarity bias involved in my case). It's actively developed and is IMO improving its usability & usefulness constantly.

Answer (score 153):

The statement about CMake being a "build generator" is a common misconception.

It's not technically wrong; it just describes HOW it works, but not WHAT it does.

In the context of the question, they do the same thing: take a bunch of C/C++ files and turn them into a binary.

So, what is the real difference?

- CMake is much more high-level.  It's tailored to compile C++, for which you write much less build code, but can be also used for general purpose build. `make` has some built-in C/C++ rules as well, but they are useless at best.
- `CMake` does a two-step build: it generates a low-level build script in `ninja` or `make` or many other generators, and then you run it. All the shell script pieces that are normally piled into `Makefile` are only executed at the generation stage. Thus, `CMake` build can be orders of magnitude faster.
- The grammar of `CMake` is much easier to support for external tools [than make's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488680/makefile-grammar).
- Once `make` builds an artifact, it forgets how it was built. What sources it was built from, what compiler flags? `CMake` tracks it, `make` leaves it up to you. If one of library sources was removed since the previous version of `Makefile`, `make` won't rebuild it.
- Modern `CMake` (starting with version 3.something) works in terms of dependencies between "targets". A target is still a single output file, but it can have transitive ("public"/"interface" in CMake terms) dependencies.
  These transitive dependencies can be exposed to or hidden from the dependent packages. `CMake` will manage directories for you. With `make`, you're stuck on a file-by-file and manage-directories-by-hand level.

You could code up something in `make` using intermediate files to cover the last two gaps, but you're on your own. `make` does contain a [Turing complete language](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/04/30/) (even two, sometimes three counting [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Guile-Integration.html)); the first two are horrible and the Guile is practically never used.

To be honest, this is what `CMake` and `make` have in common -- their languages are pretty horrible. Here's what comes to mind:

- They have no user-defined types;
- `CMake` has three data types: string, list, and a target with properties. `make` has one: string;
- you normally pass arguments to functions by setting global variables.

  - This is partially dealt with in modern CMake - you can set a target's properties: `set_property(TARGET helloworld APPEND PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`;
- referring to an undefined variable is silently ignored by default;

Comment: Some good information here, but one remark is completely wrong:  cmake has a LIST type since with proper LIST functions which is crucial for lots of build-system tasks, a bit difference: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/list.html

Comment: @VictorSergienko, Not asked in the OP's question, but I was waiting for the punch line...What do you use which you feel is better than either?

Comment: I use make for historical reasons, and I hate it. CMake is not without problems too (try cross compiling with it), but for my own projects CMake would win because you write fewer code, and it’s supported by tools.

Comment: and lets bury automake and autoconf forever please

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers CMake can generate other project files. It refers to these projects as [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

This lets users write/describe their build using a domain specific language, and use the generator to compile the project. It often results in simpler/better code than writing to these project files directly.

A big advantage is users can use the tool that they are the most comfortable with (Makefiles, Visual Studio, XCode, Ninja, etc). This is nice but arguable introduces complexity. Why not just use Ninja?

The answer is history. (As is the norm in C/C++)

Build systems like Visual Studio have tools that will only accept those project files.

For example Microsoft has a feature called "Static Driver Verifier". A tool to analyze the code of kernel mode windows drivers. However, this tool only works on Visual Studio projects since it works alongside `msbuild`.

```
msbuild /t:sdv /p:Inputs="Parameters" ProjectFile /p:Configuration=configuration /p:Platform=platform
```

If your build system can't generate Visual Studio project files, then you can't use the tool. This can be a **very big deal** for some projects/companies.