# Implement a parser from a grammar for makefiles

Tags: parsing, makefile, grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I have to write a parser for some makefiles without variables and symbols (\$@, $< etc.), all they contain are **R**ules as :

**T**arget: **D**ependencies

[tab]   **C**ommands

According to [Makefile Grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488680/makefile-grammar?answertab=active#tab-top) , the grammar of Makefile in general is context-sensitive which makes implementing a parser complicated. I tried to write the grammar of the simplified version (Fig below), but I'm not sure if it's correct and if it's context-free.

[Fig : Grammar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj2Qh.png)

I didn't detail C (commands) because the shell will parse it.

Answer (score 1):

In the productions for 'n', 'b', and 'e', the '*' presumably means that each of them can derive epsilon (empty string), which is incorrect. (It means that a D could be followed by a C without a newline or tab or even a space intervening.)

Also, it's ambiguous, which doesn't necessarily mean it's incorrect for generating the language, but probably means it's incorrect for building a parser.

- A production like `T ::= TeT` means that `T` derives `TeTeT` in 2 different ways (etc).
- A production like `n ::= n*` means any derivation from `n` can involve arbitrarily many `n -> n` steps.